# height 100% and overflow

Tags: html, css

I have my left and right column which needs to have a vertical scroll-bar. How can I achieve the the scrolling without specifying `height: 100%`

```
html,body{height:100%;}

.row > .sidebar-fixed {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left:auto;
    width: 220px;
    height: 100%;
    background: #F5F5F5;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

.left {
    float:left;
}

.right {
    float:right;
}

.fixed-fixed {
    margin: 0 240px;
}
```

The problem is to ensure I need a scroll-bar in my both div's, I have to end up specifying height for all my parent which causes issue in other layouts. Is there anyway we can bring the scroll-bar without using the `height: 100%` value.

http://www.bootply.com/FFZWQoCSJE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use fixed positioning instead:

```
.row > .sidebar-fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom:0;
  width: 220px;
  background: #F5F5F5;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.left {
  left:0;
}

.right {
  right:0;
}
```

[Example](http://www.bootply.com/Un1pwSUR1Y)

Comment: Pete... there are only two scrollbars... where is the one for the entire window which is missing?

Comment: I don't see the scroll-bar visible though?

Comment: @Shane did you try my solution?

Comment: You want the scrollbar on the content or the browser? If on the content try this: http://www.bootply.com/fPjoUEvOV9

Comment: Is it possible to get in the browser - pete.

Comment: Then in the browser the http://www.bootply.com/97TJSzcudj has a scrollbar on the right (when the content is in the main div is taller than the browser window) - if you don't have a scrollbar, shrink the height of the frame and you will see it appear

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
.row > .sidebar-fixed {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left:auto;
    width: 220px;
    height: 120px;
    background: #F5F5F5;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

And remove `{height:100%;}` from `html,body` in your CSS